# Loading BitmapImage occupies lot of memory in WP 8.1 RT

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm using a Windows Phone 8.1 RT application. One way to display an image after reading it from a file is to create a `BitmapImage` and set it as a source to the XAML `Image` control.

I'm using the following code to do the same. The image is stored in the `LocalFolder`:

```
private async void LoadImage()
{
    StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("imageFile.jpg");

    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    { 
        bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 500;
        await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);
    }

    imageHolder.Source = bitmapImage;
}
```

Since I'm loading a small part of the image, I use the `DecodePixelWidth` to conserve memory. However, my observations don't really match the expectations.

Observations:

1. If I load a `40 MB` image into memory, the memory occupied by the should increase by around `40 MB` (plus any overhead memory increase), but memory profiling of the application says otherwise. I'm seeing that the memory shoots upto `320 MB` when a `40 MB` image is loaded.
2. If I use `DecodePixelHeight` or `DecodePixelWidth` to conserve memory, the memory still shoots upto `50-80MB` (larger than size of original image), depending on the value of the `DecodePixelHeight`/`DecodePixelWidth`.

I expect the OS to use the memory judiciously and use minimum amount of memory when loading images. I expected the OS to use less than `40 MB` of memory when `DecodePixelWidth` is set, but was quite surprised to see the actual results.

Can someone explain why such high amounts of memory is used while loading images into memory? Is this the expected behavior? What can I do to conserve memory, because if things go like this, I cannot load two large images into memory at the same time without getting an OOM, even with `DecodePixelWidth`.

The profiling screenshots are attached.

1. Without using `DecodePixelWidth`, image size `40 MB.` First peak is `245 MB`, second peak is `327 MB`

[image]

2. Using `DecodePixelWidth = 500`, image size `40 MB`. First peak is `88 MB`, and the sustained level is `49 MB`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating the BitmapImage through the IRandomAccesStream you can create a compressed Thumbnail from the StorageFile.

```
StorageItemThumbnail thumb =  file.GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.ListView, 
                                                                  90,
                                                                  ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale);
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.SetSource(thumb);
```

This creates a BitmapImage that is significantly smaller than a normal BitmapImage directly from a stream.

Also if you need to load a large list of images you should look in to virtualization or even incremental lists.

Comment: I don't want to show a thumbnail; I want to load a high-res image and display it.

Comment: The three values passed to the method are ThumbnailMode, Requestedsize and ThumbnailOption. I put the requested size as 90 because i just don't need to display the images very large, just very many. but still at that size they look very well. I bet if you look into those values you will get what you need. With my application I am able to load a few hundreds of high res images without any problem with the memory.